# React native: Objects are not valid as React child

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I've really tried to read all over StackOverflow on this one since it's been asked many times before... but I can't find the solution to my error.

> Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, title, desc, location, distance}).

I'm assuming there is something wrong in this file, not sure what thou...

**PointOfInterestCluster.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity,TouchableWithoutFeedback, ScrollView } from 'react-native'
import Styles from '../../constants/Styles';

export default class PointOfInterestCluster extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        data: this.props.data,
    }

    this.onMarkerPress = this.props.onMarkerPress.bind(this);
}

renderMarkers = (item, index) => {
    console.log(item, index);
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onMarkerPress(item)} key={'markerslist_'+index}>
            <View  style={[Styles.borderBottom, Styles.borderLight, Styles.padding]}>
                <Text style={[Styles.text, Styles.textBold, Styles.textDark]}>{item.title}</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}


render() {

return (

    <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        <View>
            <ScrollView>
                <Text style={[Styles.label, Styles.padding, Styles.borderBottom]}>
                    {this.props.data.length} enheter
                </Text>
            </ScrollView>

            {this.state.data.map((item, index) => {this.renderMarker(item, index)})}
        </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

);
}}
```

PointOfInterestCluster gets called liked this:

```
{this.state.currentCluster || this.state.currentMarker &&

                <Overlay onClose={this.onCloseOverlay}>

                    {this.state.currentCluster &&
                        <PointOfInterestCluster onMarkerPress={this.onMarkerPress} data={this.state.currentCluster} poi={this.state.currentPOI}/>
                    }

                    {this.state.currentMarker &&
                        <PointOfInterest data={this.state.currentMarker} poi={this.state.currentPOI} />
                    }

                </Overlay>
            }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm right, but maybe it's a matter of style.

Comment: Hi @hongdevelop! You mean the stylesheets, I donät think so cos the error points to the 'item' object...

Comment: Ah, then, it seems good to check the type of data you receive.

Answer (score 0):

In the following line:

`{this.state.data.map((item, index) => {this.renderMarker(item, index)})}`

You're not really returning anything from the `map` function, because you have curly brackets around the `this.renderMarker` call. `renderMarker` gets called, but its result is being ignored.

You can change it to one of the following 3 alternatives which are all equivalent:
1.

```js
1.
this.state.data.map((item, index) => {
  return this.renderMarker(item, index);
});

2.
this.state.data.map((item, index) => this.renderMarker(item, index)})

3.
this.state.data.map(this.renderMarker)
```

If the problem persists, try printing the shape of your data and attaching it here.